# $\sin(k\pi/n)$ an integer multiple of $\sin(\pi/n)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, cyclotomic-fields

Is there any positive integers $(n,k) \neq (6,3)$ with $n\geq 6$ and $2\leq k\leq n/2$ such that:
$$\frac{\sin(k\pi/n)}{\sin(\pi/n)} \in \mathbb{N} ?$$
For $n\leq 57$ the answer is no (by computation), but $(n,k)= (57,22)$ is very close with $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(k\pi/n)}{\sin(\pi/n)} \simeq 17.00035063$.

Comment: $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6$ and just those.

Comment: Close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades.

Comment: @DougM: Why not amend a proof and make it an answer?

Comment: @fleablood: The prime-counting function $\pi(x)$ is close to $Li(x)$, although always a little off for obvious reasons. Some people (like Riemann) say there is a quite interesting mathematical theory lurking behind that. (I don't claim there is something profound hidden here, but I don't think your comment is as valid as it is witty.)

Comment: @DougM, why are those the only ones?

Comment: In the spirit of Fermat'  I have read a really nifty proof for this, but I don't remember where I saw it.  It came down to the requirement that sum of some series of trig functions be an integer.  If I can find it, I will post it.